# Possible redundant object creation with Optional#ofNullable?

Tags: java, option-type, premature-optimization

I'm curious about a usage of `Optional`.

With following code snippet,

```java
public List<Some> read(
    @QueryParam("first_result") @Min(0)
    final Integer firstResult,
    @QueryParam("max_results") @Min(0)
    final Integer maxResults) {

    // ...

    if (firstResult != null) {
        query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I change the code like this,

```java
ofNullable(firstResult).ifPresent(v -> query.setFirstResult(v));
```

- Question 1: Does `ofNullable` obviously creates a redundant object?
- Question 2: Is it worth for avoiding a boiler-plate code?
- Question 3: Is this question talking about premature optimization?

Comment: how is this better than the simple `if` statement?

Comment: also, the cost of creating the lambda object, and invoking the method on it; and how this complication impacts the JIT optimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. It's a matter of opinion. I personally find the code using an if block more readable, and not really more verbose
3. Yes. The cost of creating a short-lived Optional object is negligible, especially compared with executing a JPA query. So, if *you* find the optional-based code more readable and elegant, you shouldn't worry about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to prevent `firstResult` from becoming `null` in the first place, so you won't have to check for it and you can avoid easy mistakes.

How to do it? here are some options:

- If `firstResult` is the result of a method, code that method in a way
  that is guaranteed to never return `null` (and add unit tests to check
  it).
- Change the type of the field from `Integer` to `Optional<Integer>`, this way it becomes clear to the reader that this field is optional and he must check it before using it.
- Change the return type of the method that writes to `firstResult` so that it returns `Optional<Integer>`, and finish that method with `return Optional.ofNullable(result)`. This way the code that receives the result, must check the return value before storing it in the field, preventing it from becoming `null`.

There may be other ways.